# What does the timing option do under graphics in DDR?

Tags: ddr-hottest-party-3

The timing options allows me to set it from -20 to +20 at intervals of 1.

-20, -19, -18...5,6,7,8 Ect.

What does this option change? I'm moving it around between songs to try and figure it out but I cannot discern a definite noticeable difference that I can be positive isn't my mind tripping myself out.

Note: this option is not to be confused with the with the Arrow Speed Option located under INDIVIDUAL OPTIONS. I'm talking about the Timing Option located under GRAPHIC.

Comment: It probably has to do with the sync between the audio and video, +/- 20 ms or something.

Comment: @MatthewRead that rings of truth, can you confirm somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be adjustments for the time between arrows & the music. This compensates for the lag between the mat & the video.

This isn't the speed that the arrows move, just the timing of them being displayed.

Search for "timing" [in this Gamefaqs page](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/938140-dance-dance-revolution-hottest-party/faqs/50448).